# Eliminating dead space from a plot consisting of two pie charts

Tags: r, plot, pie-chart

I have this plot which I want to save as PDF.

```
pdf(file="pie_charts.pdf", width=8, height=5, onefile=F)
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,3), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE), heights=c(4, 1))
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0), xpd=TRUE)
pie(c(1,9),col=c("black","white"))
pie(c(1,3),col=c("black","white"))
plot.new()
legend(x="center", ncol=2,legend=c("Black","Whtie"),fill=c("black","white"), bty = "n",cex=1.3)
dev.off()
```

And this is what I am getting

[image]

It looks quite good but I want to eliminate as much empty space as possible between the individual pie charts as well as between them and the legend. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do it using circles instead via `symbols()` and `polygon()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just increase the `radius` of the pies:

```
layout(matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 3), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE), heights=c(4, 1))
par(mar=c(0, 1, 0, 0)) # increase left margin to accommodate text
pie(c(1, 9), col=c("black","white"), radius=1)
par(mar=c(0, 0, 0, 1)) # increase right margin to accommodate text
pie(c(1, 3), col=c("black", "white"), radius=1)
plot.new()
legend(x="center", ncol=2, legend=c("Black", "White"), 
       fill=c("black", "white"), bty="n", cex=1.3)
```

[image]

See the `radius` arg at `?pie`.

Comment: Thank you, this is the simplest solution

Answer (score 3):

With `layout()`, I think you may be a bit limited with changing margins to squeeze the pie charts together.

This isn't an elegant solution but it works.  I went in to the `pie()` function and modified the `xlim` arguments.  This was my only change.

In other words, `pie` has this inside its function:

```
xlim <- ylim <- c(-1, 1)
```

Change the `xlim` to shift the pie charts left or right.

I made `mypieleft()` and `mypieright()`.

```
mypieleft<-function(blah blah){
[untouched code from pie]
    #  xlim <- ylim <- c(-1, 1)
    xlim <- c(-1.20, 0.80)
    ylim <- c(-1, 1)
[untouched code from pie]
}
```

and

```
mypieright<-function(blah blah){
[untouched code from pie]
    #  xlim <- ylim <- c(-1, 1)
    xlim <- c(-0.75, 1.25)
    ylim <- c(-1, 1)
[untouched code from pie]
}
```

Then change your code slightly:

```
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,3), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE), heights=c(4, 1))
par(oma=c(0,0,0,0), xpd=TRUE)
mypieleft(c(1,9),col=c("black","white"))
mypieright(c(1,3),col=c("black","white"))
plot.new()
legend(x="center", ncol=2,legend=c("Black","Whtie"),fill=c("black","white"), bty = "n",cex=1.3)
```

I get this image.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is better than mine